# Devolver los valores menos repetidos de una lista

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quiero,  que de entre los últimos 100 elementos de la lista me escoja los 30 menos repetidos y me los devuelva en una lista, en caso de que tengamos varios empatados que escoja uno de los empatados al azar pero que devuelva solo 30 yo solo se contar las repeticiones de cada valor.

```
lista=[4, 18, 18, 23, 27,4,4, 0, 0,23,45,23,23,23,45,1,2,67,99,7,11]
def contarElementosLista(lista):
    """
    Recibe una lista, y devuelve un diccionario con todas las repeticiones de
    cada valor
    """
    return {i:lista.count(i) for i in lista}
```

Siguiendo la respuesta de "FJSevilla " voy así, pero hay algo que no acaba de funcionar bien

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

ultimas_bolas=[4, 18, 18, 23, 27,4,4, 0, 0,23,45,23,23,23,45,1,2,67,99,7,11]


def less_commons (ultimas_bolas: list, n: int) -> dict:
    res = {}
    less_commons_dict = defaultdict(set)

    for item, count in reversed(Counter(ultimas_bolas).most_common()):
        less_commons_dict[count].add(item)

    faltan = n - len(less_commons_dict)
    for count, items in less_commons_dict.items():
        if n == 0:
            break
        elif faltan >= 0:
            for item in items:
                res[item] = count
                faltan -= 1
                n -= 1
                if faltan < 0:
                    break
        else:
            res[items.pop()] = count
            n -= 1
    return res


py= list(less_commons(ultimas_bolas[:16], 3).keys())
print (py)
```

en este ejemplo puse que de los 15 primeros integrales me devuelva los 3 que menos se repiten y me devolvió:

```
[1, 0, 4]
```

pero no son los que menos se repiten, el 27 solo se repite una vez y no aparece, y el 0 por ejemplo esta 2 veces y si lo muestra.

Comment: no no es obligatorio el primero que aparezca es perfecto,la cuestión es elegir los 30 menos repetidos sin importar que  haya otros menos repetidos empatados , si esta todos empatados pues los 30 primeros, y si hay menos de 30 pues no se poner un condicional o algo, no lo había pensado.

Comment: Hola Samuel, el 27 aparece solo una vez, igual que el 1. Por eso no aparece, porque ya aparece el 1. Los números 1, 2, 99, 67, 7, 11, 27 aparecen solo una vez, si quieres que la salida sea [1, 2, 99], [67, 7, 11], [2, 67,  27] o cualquier combinación posible de los que se repiten una sola vez, entonces no entendí bien lo que buscabas :). si es así comenta, hay que modificar el algoritmo, por ejemplo para 9 sería [1, 2, 99, 67, 7, 11, 27,  0, 18] o  [1, 2, 99, 67, 7, 11, 27,  0, 45], o  [1, 2, 99, 67, 7, 11, 27,  45, 18] (todos los que aparecen  1 vez y dos con 2 apariciones)

Comment: Como el código para la versión alternativa comentada es muy simple he editado la respuesta añadiéndola al final, mira a ver si es lo que buscas. Cualquier cosa comenta.

Comment: ahora esta perfecto, no es que no lo entendieras es que seguramente me explique mal, jeje, gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero el código de una posible solución, después lo intentare explicar:

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict


def less_commons(lista: list, n: int) -> dict:
    res = {}
    less_commons_dict = defaultdict(set)

    for item, count in reversed(Counter(lista).most_common()):
        less_commons_dict[count].add(item)

    faltan = n - len(less_commons_dict)
    for count, items in less_commons_dict.items():
        if n == 0:
            break
        elif faltan >= 0:
            for item in items:
                res[item] = count
                faltan -= 1
                n -= 1
                if faltan < 0:
                    break
        else:
            res[items.pop()] = count
            n -= 1
    return res
```

- Se usa `collections.Counter` para contar las apariciones de los elementos, esto retorna un diccionario de la forma:

  ```
  {item1: veces_que_aparece_el_item1, item2: veces_que_aparece_el_item2, ...}
  ```
- El método `most_common` si se llama sin argumentos retorna una lista de tuplas de la forma `(item: count)` ordenada de mayor a menor según numero de apariciones. Con `reversed` invertimos dicha lista.
- En el diccionario `less_commons_dict` reordenamos la lista anterior para obtener algo como:

  ```
  {veces_que_aparecen: {item1, item2...}, veces_que_aparecen: {item3, ...}, ...}
  ```

  dónde `item1` e `item2` aparecen el mismo número de veces.
- Ahora calculamos si tenemos si tenemos suficientes "menos repetidos sin repetición", eso sería `faltan`.
- Si no faltan simplemente retornamos uno de los items de cada grupos de menos repetidos. Si faltan intentamos completar usando items con las mismas apariciones dando preferencia a los que menos aparecen.

Mejor un ejemplo:

> ```
> >>> lista = [
>     9, 47, 35, 12, 4, 28, 14, 35, 14, 40, 6, 37, 16, 11, 36, 7, 45, 28, 20, 9, 42, 33,
>     9, 12, 7, 35, 19, 31, 23, 45, 11, 26, 25, 45, 43, 10, 49, 25, 32, 21, 36, 6, 42,
>     28, 15, 39, 44, 25, 42, 43, 8, 36, 1, 39, 15, 24, 32, 49, 32, 3, 31, 42, 19, 41,
>     19, 3, 45, 18, 3, 5, 21, 47, 12, 4, 12, 22, 17, 5, 33, 30, 0, 15, 21, 19, 32, 20,
>     24, 29, 49, 23, 4, 46, 47, 21, 12, 45, 38, 48, 13, 10]
>
> >>> less_commons(lista, 5)
> {0: 1, 33: 2, 3: 3, 32: 4, 12: 5}
>
> >>> less_commons(lista, 6)
> {0: 1, 1: 1, 33: 2, 3: 3, 32: 4, 12: 5}
>
> >>> less_commons(lista, 7)
> {0: 1, 1: 1, 37: 1, 33: 2, 3: 3, 32: 4, 12: 5}
>
> >>> less_commons(lista, 26) 
> {0: 1,
>  1: 1,
>  37: 1,
>  38: 1,
>  8: 1,
>  41: 1,
>  40: 1,
>  44: 1,
>  13: 1,
>  46: 1,
>  48: 1,
>  17: 1,
>  18: 1,
>  16: 1,
>  22: 1,
>  26: 1,
>  29: 1,
>  30: 1,
>  33: 2,
>  5: 2,
>  6: 2,
>  39: 2,
>  3: 3,
>  32: 4,
>  12: 5}
> ```

El diccionario que se retorna tiene como claves el item y como valor las veces que aparece en la lista ese item. De forma que si queremos obtener solo los valores podemos usar el método `dict.keys`:

> ```
> >>> list(less_commons(lista, 7).keys())
> [0, 1, 37, 33, 3, 32, 12]
> ```

Si no es posible retornar los items requeridos retornará un diccionario de menor tamaño. En este caso el número máximo de  items es 47 (`len(set(lista))`)

---

Si no queremos que se descarten los números que aparecen igual número de veces cuando uno es tomado, sino que queremos que simplemente se retornen los `n` menos repetidos la cosa es mucho más simple:

```
from collections import Counter


def less_commons(lista: list, n: int) -> dict:
    return {
        item: count for _ , (item, count) in zip(
            range(n), reversed(Counter(lista).most_common())
            )}
```

> ```
> >>> ultimas_bolas = [4, 18, 18, 23, 27, 4, 4, 0, 0, 23, 45, 23, 23, 23, 45, 1, 2, 67, 99, 7, 11]
> >>> less_commons(ultimas_bolas, 3)
> {1: 1, 2: 1, 0: 2}
> ```

El orden dentro de los que aparecen las mismas veces depende del orden en la lista (primero los últimos).  Si queremos que sea aleatorio (pseudoaleatorio), podemos usar `random.shuffle (`in-place) o `random.sample` (nueva lista) para desordenar la lista previamente:

```
from collections import Counter
import random


def less_commons(lista: list, n: int) -> dict:
    lista = random.sample(lista, len(lista))
    return {
        item: count for _ , (item, count) in zip(
            range(n), reversed(Counter(lista).most_common())
            )}
```

> ```
> >>> ultimas_bolas=[4, 18, 18, 23, 27, 4, 4, 0, 0, 23, 45, 23, 23, 23, 45, 1, 2, 67, 99, 7, 11]
> >>> less_commons(ultimas_bolas, 3)
> {27: 1, 1: 1, 67: 1}
> >>> less_commons(ultimas_bolas, 3)
> {2: 1, 99: 1, 7: 1}
> >>> less_commons(ultimas_bolas, 9)
> {27: 1, 7: 1, 1: 1, 67: 1, 11: 1, 99: 1, 2: 1, 18: 2, 0: 2}
> ```

Comment: Gracias por tu dedicación de verdad! hay algo que no me acaba de funcionar bien, lo edite, a ver que te parece, Saludos